# What kind of softwares should be used in Vehicle Tracking System

Tags: javascript, database

If I wanted to write Vehicle Tracking Software, which software should I use for what purposes ? Can anyone explain this to me, thank you :)

Comment: Please can you specify how you intend to track the vehicles, is it by images, is it by GPS etc?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. It will be web application. There will be user and admin side of this application. User can see their vehicles and their info on the map. Yes , vehicles will be tracked by GPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a lot of different technologies to achieve your result and since the question is very broad I will answer it If I were to do it

socket.io: to enable real-time bidirectional event-based communication.

frontend: react, to display and organize incoming data

database: rethinkdb, since you can subscribe to live updates and has geospatial queries

GPS: this depends on the hardware, e.g. if it is a phone you can push gps data to rethinkdb database

these are the major pieces needed to achieve what I think you want